# Working in Norway but living in Sweden. How and where will my wife get health care?

Tags: eu-spouses, sweden, health-care, norway, russia

I am a Norwegian citizen who lives and works in Norway, very near the Swedish border. It is so close that if I move across the border, I could comfortably commute every day to my work in Norway.

My wife is a Russian citizen. Due to very stringent rules in Norway, we do not qualify for family reunification in Norway at this point. (The Norwegian authorities (UDI) demand that in 2016 my salary should have been at a certain amount, and my salary was lower than that amount in 2016. Right now my salary is high enough, but that does not satisfy UDI. They consider the previous calendar year.)

Therefore, it would be good if I moved across the Swedish border, so that she could get a residence permit in Sweden under EU freedom of movement law. I would keep working in Norway, but live in Sweden with her. As far as I understand, this is allowed under EU law.

My question is about her health care. Would she be entitled to full public health care in Sweden? Or would we have to get a private health insurance for her?

Related: [If I live in Sweden but work in Norway, how and where can I get health care?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/11477/if-i-live-in-sweden-but-work-in-norway-how-and-where-can-i-get-health-care)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in [If I live in Sweden but work in Norway, how and where can I get health care?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/11477/if-i-live-in-sweden-but-work-in-norway-how-and-where-can-i-get-health-care/12498#12498) you are covered in both countries. However your wife is **only covered fully in Sweden**.

As stated on the [EU's site on cross border workers](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/health/when-living-abroad/health-insurance-cover/index_en.htm):

> If you work and are insured in (...) **Norway**, (...) your dependants can receive treatment in the country where you **work** only when one of the following conditions is met:
>
> - treatment becomes necessary on medical grounds during their stay in that country, taking into account the nature of the treatment and the expected length of the stay
> - there is an agreement between the countries/authorities concerned
> - prior authorisation has been granted using form S2 (former E 112 form) issued by the competent health insurance authority in the country where you work.

These are similar arrangements you get when using your EHIC card abroad in an other EU/EEA country.

However, she is [still eligible](https://helsenorge.no/foreigners-in-norway/workers-from-the-eu-eea-or-switzerland-who-work-in-norway-but-do-not-live-here) to fully access Sweden's Healthcare, you just need to add her to your S1 form, when submitting it to Sweden's Health Department:

> This form [E106/S1] documents your right to necessary health care services within the public health care system **at the same level as the citizens of your country of residence**. The amount of the coverage of your expenses will depend on the law in the country in which you live.
>
> Any **dependent family members** who live together with you in your **homeland**  can be included in the form. They will receive the **same rights as yourself**.

Comment: I tried this, and I had some problems. I've asked a new question https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/12900/9674