# If I live in Sweden but work in Norway, how and where can I get health care?

Tags: working, sweden, health-care, norway

I am a Norwegian citizen. My work is in Norway, but very near the Swedish border. So, I could live in Sweden, and commute across the border every day to work in Norway. I would, of course, register as officially living in Sweden.

In such a situation, which public health care system can/must I use? The Swedish one, or the Norwegian one? Or both?

I'm talking about anything from a minor doctor's visit to serious treatment. And of course, only the public, (mostly) free health care.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on both the [EU's site on cross border healthcare](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/health/when-living-abroad/health-insurance-cover/index_en.htm) and the [Norwegian Directorate of eHealth](https://helsenorge.no/foreigners-in-norway/workers-from-the-eu-eea-or-switzerland-who-work-in-norway-but-do-not-live-here) site, you should be covered in **both** countries. You have to register yourself with Norway's Health Department to get access to Norway's healthcare:

> If you are a worker and you carry out your work in Norway and are a resident of another EU/EEA country or Switzerland, as a general rule, you must be a member of the Norwegian National Insurance Scheme.
>
> ​This means that you will be covered for necessary expenses for health care services from the public health care system and that you have to pay user fees for treatment.

Also you are covered in Sweden as well, you just need to get a form from Norway's Health Department and send it to Sweden's:

> You are also entitled to health care services in your country of residence. To document these rights, you have to get an E106/S1 form from Helfo. You need to hand in this form to the national insurance authorities in the country you live in.
>
> This form documents your right to necessary health care services within the public health care system at the same level as the citizens of your country of residence. The amount of the coverage of your expenses will depend on the law in the country in which you live.

Answer (score 0):

For questions such as this you should check the agreements between the Nordic countires; they are sometimes more favourable than the default EU arrangements. The relevant information in this case can be found at https://www.norden.org/no/info-norden/rett-til-helsetjenester-i-sverige

To quote the most relevant part:

> Syk når du bor i Sverige og arbeider i et annet nordisk land
>
> Bor du i Sverige og pendler til jobb i et annet nordisk land, vil du som regel være med i trygdeordningen i arbeidslandet. Hvis du blir syk, er du berettiget til sykepleie og tannpleie i arbeidslandet, men du kan også få tilgang til sykepleie eller tannpleie i Sverige.
>
> Du må søke om blanketten "Intyg om rätt till vårdförmåner i Sverige" hos Försäkringskassan.

But you might want to get the blue EU card that gives you the rights to healthcare similar to natives in any EU country (and some others).

> Er du med i trygdeordningen i Sverige, har du rett til det blå EU-helsetrygdkortet fra Sverige. Kortet gir deg rett til helsetjenester og tannpleie når du oppholder deg i et annet EU/EØS-land eller Sveits.

Maybe you could the card from Norway or Sweden in your case. I am not sure.