# Living in Sweden while working in Norway, Norwegian government won't give me an S1 form

Tags: eu, eu-spouses, health-insurance, sweden, norway

I'm a Norwegian citizen who lives in Sweden and commutes across the border to Norway for work. My wife is a Russian citizen who moved in with me in Sweden in November. We registered her as an EEA family member.

The Swedish authorities sent us a letter saying that she will not be covered by the Swedish health care system (since I work in Norway rather than Sweden) and that we need either a private insurance or an S1 form from Norwegian authorities.

The issue is not so much health care, we are both quite young and healthy, and we only intend to live in Sweden for a limited time. However, it looks like this issue needs to be resolved before she can even get legal residency in Sweden. That is the main matter.

This is a related to [Working in Norway but living in Sweden. How and where will my wife get health care?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/11476/working-in-norway-but-living-in-sweden-how-and-where-will-my-wife-get-health-ca) in which the accepted answer informed me that I need to get an S1 form from Norway and fill in my wife's name under family members.

I contacted the Norwegian agency HELFO, and they said that I am not eligible to fill out an S1, as S1 is not used between the Nordic countries. However the letter from the Swedish authorities requests the S1. What should I do?

I'm attaching the letter from the Swedish authorities.

[image]

[image]

Comment: if you ask for an S1 to for example Germany would they give you one? Also can't you just show them the form you received from Sweden that you need an S1? (or maybe they still want to call them their old names - E106, E109 or E121 - you might try referring to the form with these names)

Comment: @SztupY [This is the form](https://helfo.no/Lists/Skjema/Attachments/41/S%C3%B8knad%20om%20blankett%20E106-arbeidstakere-40-05.01-engelsk.pdf). I need to fill in my adress, so I can't say Germany.

Comment: I am in the same exact situation, Did you figure out to do ? I am trying to understand where to get the S1 health insurance from ? Which private health insurance companies ? I will be working in Denmark and living in Sweden

Comment: I ended up just getting a part time job in Sweden, it solved everything. 10 hours per week is enough. Alternatively, you can get a private health insurance. To get more help, you could go to http://xn--grenselskjrlighet-0rb25a.no

Answer (score 4):

> However, it looks like this issue needs to be resolved before she can
>   even get legal residency in Sweden.

This turned out to be incorrect. Even if Skatteverket had refused to register her, her stay in Sweden would still have been completely legal, as an EEA family member.

I did not manage to get an S1 from HELFO, although I suppose it might have been possible with sufficient effort.

I solved this issue by getting a part time job in Sweden to supplement my job in Norway. The person in Skatteverket who handled the case told me 10 hours a week would suffice. Getting a job solved the problem instantly, and my wife was registered and got a Swedish personal number right away. This gave her **almost** the same rights as a Swedish citizen.

It's also possible to resolve this by getting a private health insurance for the non-EEA citizen. It should be noted that Skatteverket can be rather picky with what insurance policies they accept, and this can vary on a case by case basis.

The EU initiative Solvit can often assist in this type of cases. One can start a case with them.

There is also a [special organization](http://xn--grenselskjrlighet-0rb25a.no) that specifically helps people in this situation.